# I need to convert certain jQuery upload_progress params to JavaScript

Tags: javascript

The following code is working in jQuery for ajax file upload:

```
//upload_percent = Math.ceil(upload_position / upload_total * 100);
$('.upload_progress').css('width', upload_percent + '%');
$('.upload_progress').text(upload_percent + '%');
```

HTML:

```
<div class="upload_progress" style="width:0%">0%</div>
```

Now I need to convert the above jQuery code to JavaScript in other to display upload_progress of a file.

I know in JavaScript, one can do something like the code `document.getElementById('upload_progres')` but my issue is that upload_progress is also showed in HTML div as class.

Comment: you'll want `document.querySelector` or `document.getElementsByClassName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName('upload_progress')[0]` - would select the first element with this class.  Then instead of `.width()` you should use `document.getElementsByClassName('upload_progress')[0].style.width(upload_percent + '%');` and instead of `.text()`, you need to use `.innerHTML`

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Your response is not clear to me.  Is it something like this.  
`document.getElementsByClassName('upload_progress')[0].element.style.width(upload_percent + '%');
document.getElementsByClassName('upload_progress')[0].text(upload_percent + '%');`  its not working

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('upload_progress')[0].style.width(upload_percent + '%'); ` and for the second one use `.innerHTML()` instead of `.text()`